# Remove application from Dart Editor without deleting it

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Is there a way to remove application from Dart Editor's Files tab without actually deleting the application from the disk? I have been testing several small projects and need to keep these projects for future reference but don't need them all the time loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close Folder options removes the file without deleting.